# How can i change virtual path of WCF class library

Tags: c#, wcf

How can i change virtual path of WCF class library

i can change it in WCF application project in web tab of project properties but i cannot find same option in WCF class library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the virtual path makes sense only in web hosted application. A class library alone is not in such a need because it will be hosted by an host process which could be web based like IIS or not like windows service. Why do you want to do this edit in the class library?